# How to display dropdown as I check a checkbox?

Tags: javascript, php, html

How can I display a drop-down with dynamic content when I check a checkbox in `HTML` and `JavaScript`? I have tried with some `JavaScript` contents and as I am a beginner in coding and hope my tested codes are not required here. Or can I use any other method other than the usual `JavaScript`?

```
<select id="month" name="month" class="input-text" value="<?=set_value('month',$this->input->post('month'))?>">
    <option value="<?=set_value('month',$this->input->post('month'))?>">&nbsp;&nbsp;Select Month</option>
    <option value="January" <?=($this->input->post('month') == 'January')?'selected':''?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;January</option>
    <option value="February" <?=($this->input->post('month') == 'February')?'selected':''?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;February</option>
    <option value="March" <?=($this->input->post('month') == 'March')?'selected':''?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;March</option>
    <option value="April" <?=($this->input->post('month') == 'April')?'selected':''?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;April</option>
    <option value="May" <?=($this->input->post('month') == 'May')?'selected':''?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    May</option>
    <option value="June" <?=($this->input->post('month') == 'June')?'selected':''?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    June</option>
    <option value="July" <?=($this->input->post('month') == 'July')?'selected':''?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    July</option>
    <option value="August" <?=($this->input->post('month') == 'August')?'selected':''?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;August</option>
    <option value="September" <?=($this->input->post('month') == 'September')?'selected':''?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;September</option>
    <option value="October" <?=($this->input->post('month') == 'October')?'selected':''?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;October</option>
    <option value="November" <?=($this->input->post('month') == 'November')?'selected':''?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;November</option>
    <option value="December" <?=($this->input->post('month') == 'December')?'selected':''?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;December</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try It Once Example When User Checked On Checkbox Then Select Box Will Appear Otherwise in hiding Mode .

```js
function checkfun(){
if(document.getElementById('check').checked == true){

  document.getElementById('select').innerHTML="<select style=\"width:150px;\"><option></option><option>1</option></select>";
}
  else{
 
    document.getElementById('select').innerHTML =" ";
  }
}
```

```html
<p><input type="checkbox" id="check" onchange="checkfun()"/><span id="select"></span></p>
```